# Induction: when $a_k=a_0+(k-1)d$ for any non-negative integer $k$, prove $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$

Tags: induction

> Let $a_k = a_0 + (k-1)d$ for any non-negative integer $k$, prove by mathematical induction that
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$$

My plan so far is to

**1. Produce the iteration**

$$a_1 = a_0 +(1-1)d,\qquad a_2 = a_0 +(2-1)d, \qquad \cdots, \qquad a_n = a_0 +(n-1)d,$$

Problem: can't find $a_0$.

**2. Sub lowest base value 1**

$$\frac{n\big( (a_0 +(1-1)d) + (a_0 +(n-1)d) \big)}{2} = \frac{n(a_0 d + a_0 + nd -d)}{2}$$

Not sure what I can do with this value here and am stuck.

Please, if possible, leave the answers in the simpliest form so I can understand.

Comment: If you initial term is $a_1$, you should have $a_k = a_1 + (k - 1)d$.  Then $a_1 = a_1 + (1 - 1)d = a_1 + 0d = a_1$, as expected.

Comment: Ah, makes more sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a famous trick allegedly attributed to Gauss: Let $i, j$ satisfy $i+j=n+1$. Then

\begin{align*}
a_i + a_j
&= (a_0 + (i-1)d) + (a_0 + (j-1)d) \\
&= 2a_0 + (i+j-2)d \\
&= 2a_0 + (n-1)d \\
&= a_1 + a_n.
\end{align*}

Now, by reversing the order of summation, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n+1-i}$, and so,

\begin{align*}
2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \right) + \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n+1-i} \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_i + a_{n+1-i}) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_1 + a_n) \\
&= n(a_1 + a_n).
\end{align*}

Dividing both sides by $2$ then proves the desired identity. Here is a visualization of this trick for $n = 10$:

[image: Figure 1: Visualization]

Answer (score 1):

Gauss was famous for solving this as a child. Write the sum twice, with a reversed version under the original. You get $n$ columns each summing to $a_1+a_n$. (The inductive part is verifying that, as you move to the right, each column has this sum.)